# Extracting next page and setting a break

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm trying to extract webpage data and wished to take the next few pages also but up to a limit, which I can alter. However, I've tested to see if I can at least extract the next few web-pages using Scrapy (As I'm trying to figure this out in Scrapy to learn it), but It only returns the items within the first page.

How do I extract the next pages while setting a limit i.e. 5 pages

For example, here's what I have tried:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class StatisticsItem(scrapy.Item):
    ebay_div = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())
    url = Field(output_processor=TakeFirst())


class StatisticsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ebay'
    start_urls = ['https://www.ebay.com/b/Collectible-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_1852210?rt=nc&LH_BIN=1' +
                  '&LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&_sop=16']

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url
            )

    def parse(self, response):
        all_cards = response.xpath('//div[@class="s-item__wrapper clearfix"]')
        for card in all_cards:
            name = card.xpath('.//h3/text()').get() #get name of product
            price = card.xpath('.//span[@class="s-item__price"]//text()').get() #price
            product_url = card.xpath('.//a[@class="s-item__link"]//@href').get() #link to product

            # now do whatever you want, append to dictionary, yield as item...
            summary_data = {
                "Name": name,
                "Price": price,
                "URL": product_url
            }
            data = {'summary_data': summary_data}
            yield scrapy.Request(product_url, meta=data, callback=self.parse_product_details)

            # get the next page
        next_page_url = card.xpath('.//a[@class="pagination__next icon-link"]/@href').extract_first()
        # The last page do not have a valid url and ends with '#'
        if next_page_url == None or str(next_page_url).endswith("#"):
            self.log("eBay products collected successfully !!!")
        else:
            print('\n' + '-' * 30)
            print('Next page: {}'.format(next_page_url))
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse_product_details(self, response):

        # Get the summary data
        data = response.meta['summary_data']
        data['location'] = response.xpath('//span[@itemprop="availableAtOrFrom"]/text()').extract_first()

        yield data


process = CrawlerProcess(
    settings={
        'FEED_URI': 'collectible_cards.json',
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'jsonlines'
    }
)
process.crawl(StatisticsSpider)
process.start()
```

Comment: I've got it to work in the end by replacing ```card.``` with ```response.``` in ```next_page_url```, although as with the answer below I get the issue of only 192 rows can be extracted. I'm not sure why though

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this first make urls then start start_requests

```
start_urls = ["https://www.ebay.com/b/Collectible-Card-Games-Accessories/2536/bn_1852210?LH_BIN=1&LH_PrefLoc=2&mag=1&rt=nc&_pgn={}&_sop=16".format(i) for i in range(1,5)]
```

Comment: I've tried this before but the webpage cannot scrape further than 4 pages, which is why I'm opting for extracting the 'next-page' element on the page.